# Ошибка 'Module not found:' по конфигурации webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend

При конфигурации webpack вылезает ошибка. Пробовал менять `false` у `tty http` и `fs` на `require.resolve()` как у path но ошибок стало только больше. http fs tty и соответствующие `-browserify` установлены. Я новичек в webpack так что прошу подробно объяснить в чем заключается ошибка.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/apply-source-maps.js 1:9-22 <br>
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\nikit\web_projects\Project\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader'<br>
 @ ./node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/read-sources.js 4:22-52<br>
 @ ./node_modules/clean-css/lib/clean.js 25:18-50<br>
 @ ./node_modules/clean-css/index.js 1:0-39<br>
 @ ./node_modules/html-minifier-terser/src/htmlminifier.js 3:15-35<br>
 @ ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js 1049:13-51<br>
 @ ./webpack/webpack.config.js 2:26-56
```

Конфиг:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    entry: './src/pages/ui-kit/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@ui-kit': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/pages/ui-kit'),
            // path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
        },
        fallback: {

            "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
            "os": false,
            "url": false,
            "http": false,
            "https": false,
            "assert": false,
            "util": false,
            "console": false,
            "tty": false,
            "fs": false,
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['sass-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                use: ['pug-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|)$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: '@ui-kit/index.pug'
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty'
}
```

к конфигу вебпака `webpack.config.js`.
[иссуя на гитхабе](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447)

Comment: пробовал, не помогло.
На github пока не нашел подходящее решение